# JQuery Ajax add anchor to location.reload

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've a ajax call that reload a page after a php update.

```
function Update() {

   $.post("ajax-php/actions.php", {
      action: action,
      id: id
   }, function (data) {

    location.reload();
 });
}
```

I would check if the page to reload has an anchor and if there isn't, add it to reloaded url. is possbile to do it? Thanks.

Comment: The question is very unclear to me. You are making an AJAX request to actions.php and then reloading the page. What do you mean with "anchor in page to reload"? Also you stating that you would like to add an anchor to the url when it has **NO** anchor in the page (which page?). That makes absolutely no sence to me

Comment: @RononDex - Sorry but giammin has centered my question.

Comment: What do you mean by "centered"?? Sorry but I am having a hard time understanding your english

Comment: @RononDex - no problem, forget it. thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(location.href.indexOf('#')==-1){
    location.href=location.href + '#pippo';
}
```

Some browser will not reload the page becouse of the anchor and same url, but they will scroll to that anchor.

You can trick them with a fake querystring:

```
location.href=location.href + '?p=f#pippo';
```

Comment: you've centered my problem, but now I get a duplicate url (original - index.php?id=2&op=3) with your code (index.php?id=2&op=3index.php?id=2&op=3#ancor)

Comment: @PaoloRossi I made a typo `location.href=location.href + '#pippo';` and not `location.href+=location.href + '#pippo';`

Comment: Ok, now is ok, but after adding anchor now I must reload a page because after update my page value is changed and with your method I display old data in my page.

Comment: @PaoloRossi setting `location.href` does reload your page

Comment: In fact, I would like to add the anchor and then reload. is it possibile to do it in any way? Thanks

Comment: @PaoloRossi if you redirect the user to the same page with and anchor the browser will not reload the page but scroll the page to that anchor

Comment: Ok thanks. I tried in this way. it is correct for you?       if(location.href.indexOf('#')==-1){
      location.href=location.href + '#LR';
   location.reload();
  }else {
   location.reload();
      }

Comment: or you could add a fake querystring to the url... so the browser thinks it is a different pages: `location.href=location.href + '?p=f#pippo';`